# 2D loop going through the same 10 values rather than through 100

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm not very sure how to approach this problem. Basically, I have an algorithm that loops through 100 buttons (10 rows of 10) and assigns a number value based on a randomized start and end point. When clicked, the buttons should enter the next portion of a game, and take themselves off the map. To do this, I used this code:

```
public function createMap()
    {
        var startPointX:int = int(10 * Math.random());  //creates random values that set the x and y values of the start and end points
        var startPointY:int = int(10 * Math.random());
        var endPointX:int = int(10 * Math.random());
        var endPointY:int = int(10 * Math.random());

        var spaceDiffX:int = startPointX - endPointX;   //the difference in X values
        var spaceDiffY:int = startPointY - endPointY;   //the difference in Y values

        //Creation loop - loops through all of the buttons to create them
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            mapY[i] = mapX; //Adds the rows into each column

            for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                mapY[i][j] = new LocationButton();  //Creates a new button
                mapY[i][j].x = 6 * 20 * i;  //Sets X position
                mapY[i][j].y = 6 * 10 * j;  //Sets Y position

                //places start point
                if (i == startPointX && j == startPointY)   //checks if this point on the grid is equal to the random start point
                {
                    mapY[i][j].buttonType = 1;  //sets it to the start point
                }
                //places end point
                if (i == endPointX && j == endPointY)   //checks if this point is equal to the random end point
                {
                    mapY[i][j].buttonType = 2;  //sets it to the end point
                }
                //finds path on x axis
                if (i != startPointX && j == startPointY)   //checks if this point is on the same Y value as the start point
                {
                    if (spaceDiffX >= 0)    //checks to see if the start point is on the left or right of the end point, left is negative, right is positive
                    {
                        if (i < startPointX && i >= endPointX)  //checks if i is between the start X and end X
                        {
                            mapY[i][j].buttonType = 3;  //sets it to a "shortest path point"
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i > startPointX && i <= endPointX)  //checks to see if i is between the start X and end X
                        {
                            mapY[i][j].buttonType = 3;  //sets it to a "shortest path point"
                        }

                    }

                }

                if (j != startPointY && i == endPointX) //checks if this point is on the same X value as the end point
                {
                    if (spaceDiffY >= 0)    //checks to see if the start point is over or under the end point, above is positive, below is negative
                    {
                        if (j < startPointY && j >= endPointY)  //checks if j is between the end Y and the start Y
                        {
                            mapY[i][j].buttonType = 3;  //sets it to a "shortest path point"
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (j > startPointY && j <= endPointY)
                        {
                            mapY[i][j].buttonType = 3;  //sets it to a "shortest path point"
                        }

                    }

                }

                if (mapY[i][j].buttonType != 0) //checks whether or not the button should be added
                {
                    mapY[i][j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, createBattleGUI); //adds event listener
                    stage.addChild(mapY[i][j]); //adds it to stage
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

The  problem with this is how the code after the eventListener acts, however. The function it calls starts with this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
            {
                if (mapY[i][j].buttonType != 0)
                {
                    stage.removeChild(mapY[i][j]);
                }
            }

        }
```

Once that loop goes through, it -should- remove all of the buttons. However, it doesn't. I started tracing some variables, and noticed that in the second loop, it is actually looping through the same 10 objects 10 times, instead of looping through all 100 objects. The * denotes the trace statement in the first for loop (before the event), and those without it are the buttons being traced in the second for loop:

```
name - buttonType - i - j
*instance33 1 1 6
*instance53 3 2 6
*instance73 3 3 6
*instance93 3 4 6
*instance113 3 5 6
*instance133 3 6 6
*instance153 3 7 6
*instance173 3 8 6
instance181 0 0 0
instance183 0 0 1
instance185 0 0 2
instance187 0 0 3
instance189 0 0 4
instance191 0 0 5
instance193 0 0 6
instance195 0 0 7
instance197 0 0 8
instance199 0 0 9
instance181 0 1 0
instance183 0 1 1
instance185 0 1 2
instance187 0 1 3
instance189 0 1 4
instance191 0 1 5
instance193 0 1 6
instance195 0 1 7
instance197 0 1 8
instance199 0 1 9
```

I realize that it is a bit of a long question, but I can't figure this out for the life of me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is mapX in "mapY[i] = mapX;"? I hope you are creating new array somewhere else which isn't shown in the code.

Comment: Yes, mapY and mapX are both declared as global variables at the beginning of the class.

Comment: I meant to ask how are you assigning value to maxX... looking at the code, it should have been somewhere in the outerLook of createMap()